# Deleting returned variable in python

Tags: python, variables, methods

I am writing code for python and I was wondering if it was possible to do something along the lines of this:

```
def Theoretical_Function(Variable):
    print(Variable)
    newvarcontainer = Variable
    return newvarcontainer
    #del newvarcontainer
```

aka deleting the returned variable, but still returning it from the function

Comment: What do you mean by "*deleting*'"  Please explain.

Comment: normally you can use the keyword del (variable) to remove a variable, is there anyway to do this after the variable is returned

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I think that should be gone when the garbage collector kicks in. Or you can explicitly do that.

Comment: Nothing after a `return` statement even gets executed, the function is *done*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each defined function has it's own namespace. When you exit the function(with a return statement) that namespace gets garbage collected and no other statements of the function get executed.

```
def func(a):
  print(a)
  b = a
  #the return statement exits the function
  return b
  #the following statements will NOT be executed
  a, b = 1,2
  a, b = b+1, 5
#We call the function
y = func(1)
#Now y is 1
#You cen del y and it will become inaccessible
del y
#This will throw an error:
print(y)
```

Internally Python works with references. When the statement

```
y = 1
```

gets executed, the Python interpreter reserves memory for the value 1. It will then assign the reference to the meory location of 1. When you assign another variable

```
c = 1
```

it will assign the same reference to c. You can verify this with the id-function.

```
>>> id(c)
1234567
>>> id(y)
1234567
```

Both id(c) and id(y) will return the same value, which means they point to the same location in memory. As you can see the python interpreter will store immutable values only once in memory.